# bash file check for empty file fails

Tags: bash, if-statement

I need to check if it has data it works correctly if it is empty it fails.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read _mem
do
  if [[ -s $_mem ]] ; then
    echo "$_mem"
  else
    echo "The file is empty"
  fi
done
```

I run it like this `./filechk.sh < stuff`

If the file stuff has data it prints each line of the file.  If it is empty it prints nothing.  I think it has something to do with the fact that the read fails so the loop fails but when I change it to this.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read _mem
do
  if [[ -s $_mem ]] ; then
    echo "$_mem"
  fi
done || echo "The file is empty"
```

That does not work either as even though the read fails it exits with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file exists but is empty, then in your first case, the `while` won't execute the body when the read finally fails. In the second case, the `read` fails, but the `while` does not.

So you may need to check for the empty case separately:

```
#!/bin/bash

if read _mem ; then
    echo $_mem

    while read _mem ; do
        echo "$_mem"
    done
else
    echo "File is empty"
fi
```